# How to properly access a child view controller

Tags: swift

I have a UIViewController inside a container view on my main view controller. I'm trying to un-hide the child view controller and perform a function on the child view but I don't know how to properly access it.

I've tried this:

```
let ChildVC = children.first as! ChildView
ChildVC.RunFunction()
```

But this does not work as I have multiple child views.

```
 let ChildVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Child") as! ChildView
 ChildVC.RunFunction()
```

I've then tried this, but when the RunFunction() function is executed, it throws a lot of errors saying the things inside it are nil. (The error is not with the run function as it works fine when accessing via the children.first method)

How do I specify the exact childViewController without using the children[1] (or what ever number the childViewController is) method?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The simplest way is to grab a reference to the required view controller at the time you instantiate it and add it to the container.  How are you doing that? Are you using a storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention a "container view" I am assuming you invoke the child view controller using an embed segue.

Assuming that's the case you should implement a `prepare(for:sender)` method that saves a pointer to the child:

Give the parent view controller an instance variable:

```
var childView: ChildView?
```

And then in your `prepare(for:sender)` method

```
func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if let dest = segue.destination as? ChildView {
       childView = dest
   }
}
```

Then when you need to send messages to the childView:

```
childView?.runFunction()
```

(Method names should start with lower-case letters)

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Although I would prefer something where I didn't have to rely on an essentially external class so that I could just run the function entirely in one block. But I suppose this may be the limitations of container views.